# Basic authentication on a site from a remote server not working

Tags: iis-7, forms-authentication, asp.net-4.0, basic-authentication

I setup a really basic authentication schema using a SHA1 pw and credentials stored in web.config.

After deploying the .Net 4.0 site (in IIS 7), I can successfully login when I go to the www location from the server the site resides on.

However when trying to login from a browser on another computer, putting in the appropriate credentials just cycles right back to the login screen.

In the site's IIS Authentication, I enabled Anonymous, Basic and Forms.

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <!-- <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/> -->
      <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/AdminPages/Default.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies"  timeout="30">
        <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
          <user name="user1" password="77A80B8DE9F00DD1CC502344C38FC1BA24CC0897" />
          <user name="user2" password="329E66AD5EC6E09AA8002311ACAF6ADBACD12DC4" />
        </credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <location path="Styles">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Account">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="AdminPages">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="user1,user2"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following configuration, I was able to achieve the desired user-based authentication with credentials stored in the Web.config with SHA1 pw encryption.  Hope it helps someone:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="~/AdminPages/Website.aspx" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="1000">
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
      <user name="baden1" password="77A80B8DE9F00DD1CC502344C38FC1BA24CC0897"/>
      <user name="bruno1" password="329E66AD5EC6E09AA8002311ACAF6ADBACD12DC4"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="admin"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```